# TeX Live Utility Update Failed

Tags: texlive

I am trying to update my TeX Live Utility so I can update my distribution, but when I attempt to update, it fails for some reason.  I am using a Mac.  Here is what the log says about the problem:

```
2015-03-10 08:30:57 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[589]   Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater.....................................................................................
............................................................................................
.....
2015-03-10 08:30:57 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[589]  ./runme.sh: line 11: kpsewhich:
 command not found

2015-03-10 08:30:57 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[589]  ./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live 
root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.

2015-03-10 08:30:57 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[589]  ./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as
 needed, otherwise it's hopeless.

2015-03-10 08:30:57 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][399]
kqueue noted that pid 590 exited (/var/folders/d_/f_t6bp352kzfkh654mqsr9280000gn/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.jNERhr/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11)

2015-03-10 08:30:57 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[589]   child process pid = 590 exited

2015-03-10 08:30:58 +0000 Error tlu_ipctask[589]    Value of errno is No such file or directory

2015-03-10 08:30:58 +0000 Error tlu_ipctask[589]    *** ERROR *** exit status of pid = 590 was 1

2015-03-10 08:30:58 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][399]
waitpid returned 589, WIFEXITED(256) = 1, errno = 93 (Attribute not found)

2015-03-10 08:30:58 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][399]  
kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 589) exited with status 1

2015-03-10 08:30:58 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation main][399]   
Removed temp directory "/var/folders/d_/f_t6bp352kzfkh654mqsr9280000gn/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.jNERhr"

2015-03-10 08:31:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMLogWindowController awakeFromNib][399]    
Loaded log window controller
```

UPDATE (several hours after original post): I tried updating manually via Terminal, and presumably it worked.  However, when I then tried to update my packages via Texlive Utility, it downloaded for a while but at the end another error occurred.  It seems the process was successful up until near the end, where these errors appear in the log:

```
2015-03-10 13:18:12 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex ...


2015-03-10 13:20:06 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex.

2015-03-10 13:20:06 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine eptex ...

2015-03-10 13:21:00 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine eptex.

2015-03-10 13:21:00 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine aleph ...

2015-03-10 13:21:52 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine aleph.

2015-03-10 13:21:52 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine uptex ...

2015-03-10 13:22:41 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine uptex.

2015-03-10 13:22:41 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine ptex ...

2015-03-10 13:23:32 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine ptex.

2015-03-10 13:23:32 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine euptex ...

2015-03-10 13:24:28 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine euptex.

2015-03-10 13:24:28 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt mf ...

2015-03-10 13:25:19 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt mf.

2015-03-10 13:25:19 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt cont-en ...

2015-03-10 13:26:20 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt cont-en.

2015-03-10 13:26:20 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfcsplain ...

2015-03-10 13:27:14 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfcsplain.

2015-03-10 13:27:14 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt lualatex ...

2015-03-10 13:28:05 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt lualatex.

2015-03-10 13:28:05 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt dvilualatex ...

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  done running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt dvilualatex.

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
var/tex/generic/config/language.dat" ...

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
var/tex/generic/config/language.dat" failed (status 127), output:

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  sh: fmtutil-sys: command not found

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
var/tex/generic/config/language.def" ...

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
var/tex/generic/config/language.def" failed (status 127), output:

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  sh: fmtutil-sys: command not found

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  running fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua" ...

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  fmtutil-sys 
--no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua" failed (status 127), output:

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  sh: fmtutil-sys: command not found

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[903]  

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Notice -[TLMLogServer _parseMessageAndNotify:][718]   
Unhandled status "exiting "

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[903]   exiting tlmgr:

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][718]  
kqueue noted that pid 904 exited (/usr/texbin/tlmgr --repository 
http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet/ --machine-readable --persistent-downloads 
update --all)

2015-03-10 13:28:55 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[903]   child process pid = 904 exited

2015-03-10 13:28:56 +0000 Error tlu_ipctask[903]    Value of errno is No such file or directory

2015-03-10 13:28:56 +0000 Error tlu_ipctask[903]    *** ERROR *** exit status of pid = 904 was 1

2015-03-10 13:28:56 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][718]  
waitpid returned 903, WIFEXITED(256) = 1, errno = 2 (No such file or directory)

2015-03-10 13:28:56 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][718]  
kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 903) exited with status 1
```

Comment: Can you look at what repository is being used?

Comment: This is the address: http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet/  I am located in Nepal so this is probably why it's an Indian site.

Comment: Quite strange. Can you try issuing `sudo tlmgr update --self` from a terminal window? The administrator password will be asked for; don't worry, it's safe.

Comment: I did this, and I guess it updated the utility.  However, when I tried to then update my packages by means of the Texlive Utility, it downloaded for a while and then failed again.  I put the log results in the question above.

Comment: TLU developer here: I can't reproduce the problem using that mirror. My guess is either that you last updated in late December, when TeX Live was broken, or you migrated from Yosemite and Apple's installer messed things up. Feel free to email me <amaxwell AT mac DOT com> if you can help debug this problem; I need more info.

Comment: Yes, I did update around December 2014, possibly early January.  I also upgraded my Mac OS to Yosemite shortly thereafter.

Comment: From what I read there is that somehow the PATH settings are messed up, otherwise the first kpsewhich call should work. Could it be that you set the PATH somewhere where it is *not* normally evaluated, but only when you run an interactive shell? In this case processes spanned by TLU might not see the programs.

Comment: I definitely have not tinkered with the PATH or other settings.  I don't have the knowledge to be able to do that, so my hands are tied to a certain extent.

Comment: Somehow this seems to have sorted itself out.  This morning I opened the Texlive Utility and it asked me to install the new version.  I did so with no problem and then updated my packages without a hitch.  For future reference, how often is good to update all one's packages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because some days late the update runs without problems (see last comment of OP).